# Extend the Linux Native Pratition Disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I need little help to figure out the Way to Extend the Disk Size of Linux Native Partition.

Here is the Output of `df -h`

[image]

As you See here `/dev/sda1` is boot Partition and I would Like to extend the Size of `/dev/sdb1` which is Only Data Drive where all the Data is Stored and at the Moment this is `1 TB` and i want to Extend it to `1.5 TB`. i can use `Gparted` for it. but my Main concern is **How Long does it Gonna Take** ?
I think extending form `1Tb to 1.5` Tb will take more than hours.
is there is Another way to Extend it Fastly ?

Please Share Little Help.
thanks

Comment: I have extended a partition before and it took about 2 minutes for 5 gigs of change on a slow drive, so for 500 gigs on a decently fast drive would theoretically take about 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into a live system so no partition is mounted, then open GParted. Make sure swap isn't used either (if you have a swap partition) by right-clicking it and choosing "swap off".

Then resize your partitions as you choose. Resizing from the right hand side of a partition is generally fast, resizing from the left and moving a partition is generally slow. There is a program called "Disks" which you can open from the dash. It comes with a benachmark tool for drives. Make sure only to perform a read benchmark. Use the mean value and approximate the data which has to be copied. This gives you a rough estimate of how long it's going to take.

Keep in mind that playing with partitions is dangerous, especially if there is a power failure, so make sure to have a backup. If you have to make one in advance, use the mean value from the bench mark for an estimate and the tool `dd` do make the backup. The estimate for this one should be pretty accurate if you're using an external hard drive with usb 3.0 for the backup. If yours is usb 2.0, it'll take a lot longer. 30 MB/s as an estimate.

Comment: Well , to add little more Info , this Linux Machine is VM over the Hyper V

Comment: I didn't see that you're talking about 2 different disks (`/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`). The information you still can take from my answer: If you can expand `/dev/sdb` to the right, it'll go really fast. I'm talking about seconds here.

Comment: So what i have understood from your Text is that i need to At first Unmount the `/dev/sdb` and then Just Use Gparted to Extend it and i have checked it there is No Swap Memory

Comment: i didnt understand what you mean with this paragraphs.** Then resize your partitions as you choose. Resizing from the right hand side of a partition is generally fast, resizing from the left and moving a partition is generally slow. There is a program called "Disks" which you can open from the dash. It comes with a benachmark tool for drives. Make sure only to perform a read benchmark. Use the mean value and approximate the data which has to be copied. This gives you a rough estimate of how long it's going to take **

Comment: Let's say your partition starts at 5 and goes to 14 (just some points on your disk). You want to increase its size by 5. When the new size is from 5 to 19, GParted is like "Oh, hey, just got to make it bigger to the right", so it sets the new end point to 19  and is done. In a second. If your new size is from 0 to 14, it first has to copy all of the data between 5 and 14 to the space between 0 and 9. This takes a lot of time (which depends on how fast your HDD can copy).  Then it increases the size of the partition from 0 to 9 to the new size 0 to 14. This, again, is done within a second.